# What is this part that came with my eggbeater pedals?

Tags: parts, pedals

I bought some second-hand Crank Bros Eggbeater pedals. They came in the original box, apparently with all the bits except the cleats. (That's fine. CB cleats are effectively a consumable.)

One of the bits is a pair of plastic pieces I don't recognize. Please enjoy these ASCII drawings:

```
  ___     ,     ,       ___
 / _ \    |__   |__    /   \
( (_) )   |▓▓   |__   (  *  )
 \___/    |     |      \___/
 Front   Side   Side    Back
               Cutaway
```

Each piece is a plastic disc with a knurled edge. From the disc, a ring is extruded, with threading on the outside of the ring. The ring's inner diameter is 10mm, and the outside is ~13.5mm. The outside diameter *seems* to be the same as a pedal spindle diameter, but the threading has a different pitch. There's also a very small hole through the centre of the disc, so it can't be used to seal anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without a picture it sounds like the grease port tool

[image: grease gun and port tool]

This picture was found in [this article on rebuilding eggbeater pedals](https://pedaldamnit.blogspot.com/2007/05/crank-brothers-eggbeater-servicing.html).

> The Crank Brothers Eggbeater pedals, however, require periodic lubrication. A maintenance interval of once per season seems to be the general consensus.
>
> As the Eggbeaters come with a grease port attachment, I purchased a grease gun

Evidently Eggbeater supplies the fitting but someone there does not recommend using it.

> It seems like a painless, 5-minute job: remove dust cap; install grease port attachment; squirt in new grease, wipe off the old grease (pushed out from the seals on the inboard side); reinstall dust cap; and you are done.
>
> Call me anal, but I decided to double-check with the manufacturer — and I am glad I did:
>
> > Hello,
> >
> > Thank you for your e-mail.
> > ...we would suggest not using the grease port. We would rather you take the spindle out and  grease it like that. Just unscrew the endcap and take the nut  off -  then pull the spindle out and re-grease.
> >
> > Hopefully this helps,
> >
> > Thanks
> >
> > Anka Martin
> > anka@crankbrothers.com
> > Customer Service
> >
> > [www.crankbrothers.com](http://www.crankbrothers.com)

Here is [another article with slightly better pictures](http://www.cs.unca.edu/%7Eboyd/touring/eggbeater/eggbeater.html).
[image: grease gun, cleats, shims, and grease port tool]

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely the part in those pictures. And the "Hey, we gave this to you, but don't use it" official guidance is probably why the CB pedals I had bought (new) in the past did not come with the grease port.

Comment: Speedplay pedals used a grease port, and at first, you had to pry off the endcaps and push in a grease gun fitting that you had to buy. Later, they added a screw and a hole to the standard endcaps. In my experience, this never worked great, grease was squirting everywhere including back towards the user, and it was a lot of grease. In retrospect, it was better to disassemble the pedals and clean them. However, SP bonded the pedal nut to the pedal, which you needed a soldering iron to undo. Anyway, it looks like CB went the right way.